# Qt - Image merged multiple times gets smaller, includes a "border"

Tags: c++, image, qt

I'm having trouble with Qt.

I'm writing an app that takes a PNG file from database, and allows you to apply multiple layers (each representing a different set of multiple-choice elements (also from database) for different areas of the base PNG), and displays the result within QGraphicsView Widget. However, when I merge the original image with an element, the original gets smaller and gets a "border" around it. 
Examples: 
Original image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/CP83Z.png (sans black area) 
The black element is another PNG, in which there's the element and it's surrounded by transparency.  
Result after few merges - https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpdj3.png

What the hell? The QGraphicsView is 520x520 and doesn't touch any other Widget. I have to get the app to be able to merge the contents of QGraphicsView multiple times without any kind of movement/resizing, as there will be lots and lots of undecided clicking between various elements and layers.

The app works like this: I have two dynamicly generated arrays of buttons with images taken from database, let's say the Base list and Elements list. When I click a button in the Base list, it's loaded into the main QGraphicsView. Now I am supposed to be able to add elements onto that loaded image by clicking buttons on the other list. I do that by getting the content of QGraphicsView widget and drawing the element using a QPainter.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() //placeholder for merging testing
{
    QPixmap element("C:\\Users\\Petersaber\\Desktop\\warstwa1.png");

    QPixmap base = QPixmap::grabWidget(ui->QGraphicsView);
    base= oryginal.scaled(QSize(520,520),Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation); //resized to QGV
    element= element.scaled(QSize(520,520),Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation); //resized for QGV
    QPainter painter(&base);
    painter.drawPixmap(0,0,element);

    //the error happens somewhere later from this point
    QGraphicsScene* sceneElement = new QGraphicsScene();
    QGraphicsPixmapItem* dodany = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(base);

    sceneElement->addItem(dodany);
    ui->QGraphicsView->setScene(sceneElement);
    ui->QGraphicsView->fitInView(sceneElement->sceneRect(),Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
    ui->QGraphicsView->show();
}
```

My guess is that for some reason it takes more than just what's INSIDE of the QGraphicsView, it also takes the 1-2 pixels around it, but why? How to prevent that? I have no idea. I'm a total newbie to Qt, I've only started two days ago.
edit: I am wrong. That's not how it works. The error happens AFTER the merging. Wtf?

It happens regardless of what size the merged images are. After every merge, two white pixels and 1px border always appear between the merged image and the QGraphicsView edge.

**edit**:  I've discovered that the 2px margin is hard-coded into QGraphicsView::fitInView(). I have no idea how to work around that. I've found pieces of code, such as this,

```
QRectF removeMargin11945(const QRectF& sceneRect, const QSize& viewerSize){
    const int bugMargin = 2;
    const double mx = sceneRect.width()/viewerSize.width()*bugMargin;
    const double my = sceneRect.height()/viewerSize.height()*bugMargin;
    return sceneRect.adjusted(mx, my, -mx, -my);
}
```

, but I don't know how to implement that

Comment: The problem is definitely in accumulated extra pixels. You need to check function calls that resize the images. Pay attention to this call too `ui->QGraphicsView->fitInView(...)`. Also you can verify the sizes of `base` and `element` images after scaling. In other words - just debug your code.

Comment: The images are scaled properly. I'm fiddling with fitInView and no luck

Comment: @vahancho I've discovered that the 2px margin is hard-coded into QGraphicsView::fitInView(). I have no idea how to work around that

Comment: What if you call `ui->QGraphicsView->fitInView(sceneElement->sceneRect().adjusted(0, 0, 2, 2),Qt::KeepAspectRatio);`?

Comment: @vahancho adjusted() doesn't make a bit of difference

Comment: @vahancho ok, problem solved. adjusted() helped, I was just doing it wrong. The correct values were (3, 3, -3, -3), anything else didn't do a damn thing or broke it even more. However, that caused scrollbars to appear, and every new layer would include them when grabbing existing picture. QGraphicsView takes it's policy from QAbstractScrollArea, and I set both vertical and horizontalScrollBarPolicy to ScrollBarAlwaysOff. Now it works perfectly. Thanks for setting me on the right path! I missed adjusted() when doing my research earlier